# Download only private modules from internal go proxy and get the public ones from the an external proxy

Tags: go, module, go-modules, goproxy

I got started with migrating a Go project to use modules for dependency management. My company has an internal go proxy that hosts PRIVATE modules ONLY. So, I need a way to download the PRIVATE modules from the internal proxy, let say `goproxy.company.com` and the public modules like the `golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports` and `github.com/sirupsen/logrus` from a publicly available go proxy like `proxy.golang.org`. I was thought this would solve it.

`GOPROXY='goproxy.company.com,proxy.golang.org,direct'`

`GPPRIVATE=*.company.com/*`

But, it fails after trying out the first proxy and the second and never uses the `direct` option as a fallback. Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong here?

Is there a better way to do this? Are the corporate internal proxies expected to host the publicly available go modules are well? Is this the general expectation?

I get that feeling after reading the docs. Here are the references.

> As mentioned in the [Proposal: Secure the Public Go Module Ecosystem](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/25530-sumdb.md)
>
> > We expect that corporate environments may fetch all modules, public and private, through an internal proxy;

> Also, in the [go docs](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Module_configuration_for_non_public_modules) example for a corporate proxy
>
> > For example, if a company ran a module proxy serving private modules, users would configure go using:
> >
> > ```
> > GOPRIVATE=*.corp.example.com 
> > GOPROXY=proxy.example.com 
> > GONOPROXY=none
> > ```
> >
> > This would tell the go command and other tools that modules beginning
> > with a corp.example.com subdomain are private but that the company
> > proxy should be used for downloading both public and private modules,
> > because `GONOPROXY` has been set to a pattern that won't match any
> > modules, overriding `GOPRIVATE`.

Answer (score 1):

Go 1.15 added a feature which now allows you to set up `GOPROXY` to skips proxies.

From [Go 1.15 Release Notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.15):

> The GOPROXY environment variable now supports skipping proxies that
> return errors. Proxy URLs may now be separated with either commas (,)
> or pipe characters (|). If a proxy URL is followed by a comma, the go
> command will only try the next proxy in the list after a 404 or 410
> HTTP response. If a proxy URL is followed by a pipe character, the go
> command will try the next proxy in the list after any error. Note that
> the default value of GOPROXY remains https://proxy.golang.org,direct,
> which does not fall back to direct in case of errors.

This should allow you to set up `GOPROXY` as you're indicating in your question.